# Springboot Strange Resource Loading Behavior

Tags: spring-boot, classpath

I'm working on a springboot 1.5.1 application that I'm trying to load a WSDL included in my resources directory in the wsdl directory.  Depending on where my application executes I'm getting different results (command line, intellij, cloud foundry) and I can't seem to get all three to work at the same time.

I've tried several ways of locating the resource:

From prior to the migration to springboot we had this (worked in IntelliJ but not java -jar myboot.jar):

```
this.getClass().getResource("/wsdl/my.wsdl");
```

I switched it to the typically more correct version and got it to work in IntelliJ and java -jar but not Cloud Foundry:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/wsdl/my.wsdl");
```

I switched it to use the Spring Resource Loader version and it worked in IntelliJ and CloudFoundry but not java -jar:

```
@Value("classpath:/wsdl/my.wsdl")
private Resource wsdlResource;

wsdlResource.getURL();
```

On the command line what I've noticed is that it seems to be thinking that BOOT-INF/classes is a JAR file (Note the ! after classes):

> Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: jar:file:/C:/dev/redacted/build/libs/redacted.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/wsdl/my.wsdl. It failed with:
>           JAR entry BOOT-INF/classes!/wsdl/my.wsdl not found in C:\dev\redacted\build\libs\redacted.jar.

From looking at IntelliJ's URL, it's referring to the actual source folder which explains why it seems to always work.

What is causing this and how might I universally load these class path resources successfully with springboot?

Comment: What code/library is it that's trying to load the WSDL? It looks like it doesn't support Spring Boot's fat jars. Can you share a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I think I'm mostly concerned about the behavior of the resource loading including BOOT-INF/classes as a JAR and if there's perhaps a way to turn that path into something a more primitive library could use.  I don't have a full appreciation for what Boot is doing here and have had a poor time trying to get documentation for this issue.  It sounds like this might be expected behavior?

Comment: It's expected behaviour for a library that doesn't load resources from the class path in a robust manner. As an alternative, you could try shading your application's jar.

Comment: It's just a wsimport generated client.  But the path given by all the classpath resource loading is treating BOOT-INF/classes as a jar within my jar.  That seems to be why the trouble is happening.  Do you know of some example code from within Spring that I could reference to see a successful loading of a resource?  It doesn't have to be a WSDL